# How to use MassTransit InMemory?

Tags: c#, masstransit

I want to register consumer **by interface**, send message, initialize it **by interface** from container, then consume:

```
public sealed class TestConsumer<T> : IConsumer<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<ConsumeContext<T>, Task> _onConsume;
    private readonly EventWaitHandle _handle;
    public TestConsumer(Func<ConsumeContext<T>, Task> onConsume)
    {
        _onConsume = onConsume;
        _handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<T> context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _onConsume(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            _handle.Set();
        }
    }

    public async Task GetTask()
    {
        while (!_handle.WaitOne(0))
            await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}


public class MyRequest { }

[TestFixture]
public class ConsumerTests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        var tc = new TestConsumer<MyRequest>(async (c) => Console.WriteLine("request"));
        services.AddSingleton<IConsumer<MyRequest>>(tc);
        services.AddSingleton<IBusControl>(x => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("foobar", c => { c.Consumer<IConsumer<MyRequest>>(x); });
        }));

        var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        await sp.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>().StartAsync();

        //and how do I send it?
        //this will obviously not work with Uri!!!
        var sendEndpoint = await sp.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>().GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("foobar", UriKind.Relative));
        await sendEndpoint.Send(new MyRequest());

        await tc.GetTask();
        Console.WriteLine("done");
    }
}
```

Honestly, lack of documentation is driving me crazy. There is such thing as harness, but it works only if you throw your DI container into garbage can or write a ton of adapters.

How do one can use InMemory and combine it to completely uncompatible Uri in Send method?

Comment: I'd suggest [looking at the container-specific versions of the test harness](https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.0.4.html#in-memory-test-harness). Also, the code above makes zero sense, I'm not sure why you'd ever use it.

Comment: Thank you, but it will not help me to separate IoC from masstransit configuration and make it work somehow, hence will not be able to test it without boilerplate. Example I provided - just a stub, so you will not drown in business logic and can concentrate on problem.